# Nintendo Game Boy emulation using Cortex M3

Tags: arm, cortex-m3

I am planning to build a Nintendo Game Boy simulator using ARM Cortex M3 processor.

I have no idea how to interface with the game cassette. Could anyone give some hints about it?

Comment: Wow that sounds like a rather large project... Are you talking about the connector or what the conductors are doing?

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of resources out there for Game Boy development. [GBDev Wiki](http://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/) has lots of information including [schematics](http://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/DMG_Schematics).

You will have to find a source for the physical cartridge slot itself. You may need to find a dead device to cannibalize the part from.

Answer (score 0):

Divide the problem in half, download roms first, work on the emulator and display and buttons and all that which may or may not end up being a huge task.  Then worry about the cartridge.

You may end up wanting to read the cartridge all at once then just run the emulator against an image in RAM (or read it to flash if you dont have enough RAM).  The I/O reading the cartridge may or may not be a bottleneck that slows down the emulation speed (thus you may want to read it all at once, one time, and make a copy in RAM or flash).

You will need a microcontroller that has enough I/O to read the flash, and will probably need 5 V I/O for the cartridge where your microcontroller is probably going to be 3.3 V, not a big deal but something to not forget.

The schematics pointed to by Madmanguruman should give you an idea on the cartridge, take a working Game Boy system, take the cover off the cartridge, probe the board and figure out Vcc vs ground and the rest of the pins are likely to be obvious from there.

Comment: Caching the entire cartridge in RAM isn't a bad idea, but Wikipedia says 256K - 8M for the original gameboy's cartridges, which is more than the on-board RAM of any Cortex part I'm familiar with and more than the flash of most.  Chances are the Cortex will be enough faster than the chip it is emulating to be able to read the cartridge as fast as the original ~4Mhz processor did.

Comment: Get a M3 that supports an external memory bus, and it will make your life a lot easier: http://www.silica.com/product/lpc178x7x-arm-cortex-m3-mcu-with-external-memor.html

Comment: @pjc50 - and put 8MB of ram on the board?  Can't say I think that sounds easier.

Comment: No, use the external memory bus to access the cartridge directly. If I'm understanding http://gbdev.gg8.se/wiki/articles/DMG_Schematics correctly, the cartridge pinout _is_ a 16-bit read-write memory bus. Assuming the controller can achieve the desired timings, it can be used directly. http://fms.komkon.org/GameBoy/Tech/ claims carts are from 256kbit, not byte (wikipedia error?)

Comment: things like that are measured in bits, memories are generally measured in bits not bytes (when bought at the chip level, as modules often described in bytes).